#  initWithFrame: method in HGKOptionPanel Library

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

There is an ios library called [HGKOptionPane](https://github.com/Hegaka/HGKOptionPanel) by Jon Arrien. It is a show/hide dropdown panel. While I was implementing it to my demo app, I noticed this UIView frame linked with the UIButton.
I'm sure it has something to do with the code below, I didn't understand the code and I would appreciate if you could explain it. Most importantly, how is the `UIButton` linked with the UIView or `Option Panel` it self.

The 2 methods inside HGKOptionPanel.m :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    isExpanded = YES;
}
```

Photo:
[image]

`Option Panel` is the `UIView` with black Background color.

Comment: Again guys, in the Interface Builder I see no link attached to `Option panel`. Though, it still response to the method `controlPanelShowHide`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIButton is an IBOutlet which is not linked by code.
It is actually all saved in the xib file here:
https://raw.github.com/Hegaka/HGKOptionPanel/master/HGKOptionPanel/HGKOptionPanel/en.lproj/MainWindow.xib